# Careers UI Suggestion: Change "file your CV" to "my CV"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, user-interface

I have a minor suggestion that may help navigation for the new careers.stackoverflow.com site. See this image:

[image]

I suggest you change the "file your CV" tab to read "my CV".

My reasons:

1. The link takes you to a page titled "My CV"
2. The tab is primarily for returning users who have filed a CV; new users will read the instructions and follow the link on the home page, which rightly contain the phrase "file your CV".
3. It's more personal.

Anyway, just a suggestion.

Comment: +1 - I was lost trying to find my cv

Comment: @Juan Manuel: Yeah, it took me several minutes of head scratching before I just started randomly clicking on links. Hence my suggestion.

Comment: Good suggestion, working on it now. Should go live tomorrow.

Comment: +1 for freehand circles!

Comment: @alexanderpas: and free-hand arrows... don't forget that.....

Comment: @Matt Sherman: looks like it's gone live. Thanks!

Comment: @Matt Sherman: Also, can you add an answer mentioning that it's complete so I can accept it? We gotta build that rep up! :)

Comment: We were unable to implement the red circle and arrows. Waiting for HTML5.

Comment: @Matt Sherman: try using jQuery!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been added. Thanks for the suggestion!